# Severe: PWC6117: File "null" not found when loading page with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, glassfish

Using jQuery, I'm loading my header and my footer into every webpage (e.g. index.jsp). My application runs on a GlassFish 4.1+ server with NetBeans. Recently, when loading the webpage, I get the following error in the GlassFish console:

```
Info:   Loading application [test] at [/test]
Info:   test was successfully deployed in 580 milliseconds.
Severe:   PWC6117: File "null" not found
```

The console has the same output as always, it's only that this line is added. I have debugged the project and narrowed the issue down to coming from the following line in `index.jsp`:

```
$(function () { $("footer").load("constructables/footer-desktop.jsp"); });
```

The line above, the exact same function is run, but for loading the header (so `$("header")` and `"constructables/header.jsp"`). This same setup worked flawlessly before. The rest of the page, inculding the loading of the `header.jsp`, is loading just fine.

I've tried restarting the server, restarting my computer, undeploying and deploying the application in GlassFish, but nothing seems to work. Also Google searches don't offer any help. What causes this problem and how can it be fixed?

Thanks